# Invalid byte 1 of 1-byte UTF-8 sequence from ANT

Tags: java, tomcat, ant, wsdl

```
 [java] - generating IBulkInvoiceAPI.wsdl
     [java] [Fatal Error] :3:544805: Invalid byte 1 of 1-byte UTF-8 sequence.
     [java] java.lang.RuntimeException: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: Invalid byte 1 of 1-byte UTF-8 sequence.
     ...
     [java] Exception in thread "main"
```

I am getting this exception in the time of running ANT.
I am using java version 1.4.

Finally it is showing

```
BUILD FAILED
<project_path>\build.xml:311: The following error occurred while executing this line:
<project_path>\bin\deploy-base.xml:108: The following error occurred while executing this line:
<project_path>\bin\deploy-base.xml:187: The following error occurred while executing this line:
<project_path>\bin\soap-gen.xml:13: Java returned: 1
```

Comment: Are there lines starting with "at"?

Comment: @stark, yes inside the exception

Comment: Those tell you on what line in your code your error occurs.